# Weird Minecraft crash

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I get launched into the game and continue a saved map, the game suddenly crashes... why?
This is what the launcher shows:

```
[11:27:46] [Server thread/WARN]: Can't keep up! Did the system time change, or is the server overloaded? Running 5916ms behind, skipping 118 tick(s)
[11:29:42] [Client thread/ERROR]: ########## GL ERROR ##########
[11:29:42] [Client thread/ERROR]: @ Post render
[11:29:42] [Client thread/ERROR]: 1282: Invalid operation
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x26ff4960, pid=228, tid=644
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_91-b15) (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.91-b15 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig4icd32.dll+0x44960]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\MAYUR\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid228.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [this bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8139207), a potential solution is to add `-Dforge.forceNoStencil=true` to the Java command line parameters.

To do this in Minecraft, go to Edit Profile in your Minecraft Launcher, click the "Enable JVM Arguments" checkbox near the bottom, and add `-Dforge.forceNoStencil=true` to the end of whatever text might be there.

[image: Fixing a native OpenGL error in Minecraft]

Just like this.

Comment: But it says:Invalid initial young generation size: -Xmn128M;-Dforge.forceNoStencil=true;